# Select from Multiple List inside cascading DropDownList using condition in Linq query c#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-web-api, gridview

I need to select from **Different list from different tables in one cascading DropdownList** from one Database named *TrialEntities17* as per the value of **Loss_Type**

This is the part where I need some help since I'm unable to get Output *return all*

```
private List<LOSS_TYPE_MASTER> populateState()
    {
        // here code for populate state
        List<LOSS_TYPE_MASTER> all = new List<LOSS_TYPE_MASTER>();
        using (TrialEntities17 dc = new TrialEntities17())
        {
            all = dc.LOSS_TYPE_MASTER.ToList();
        }
        return all;

    }

      
    private List<string> populateCity(int Loss_Type)

    {
        using (TrialEntities17 dc = new TrialEntities17())
            // here code for populate city based on stateID
            if (Loss_Type == 1)
        {
            List<LINE_CONFIGRATOR> all = new List<LINE_CONFIGRATOR>();

                all = dc.LINE_CONFIGRATOR
                            .Where(a => (a.Line_Name == DropDownList1.SelectedValue && a.Loss_Type.Equals(Loss_Type) && a.STATION == L2.Text)).ToList();
            }

            else if (Loss_Type == 2)
        {
            List<LINE_SKILL_CONFIG> all = new List<LINE_SKILL_CONFIG>();

                all = dc.LINE_SKILL_CONFIG
                            .Where(b => (b.Line_Name == DropDownList1.SelectedValue && b.Loss_Type.Equals(Loss_Type) && b.STATION == L2.Text)).ToList();
        }
        return all;
    }
```

Here I'm having populateState Dropdownlist where I select Loss_Type, I need populateCity Dropdownlist to select List of data on the basis of Loss_Type selected.

[image]

My entire cs code is below,

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.Entity.SqlServer;

namespace Loss_Portal
{
    public partial class _Default : Page
{

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsPostBack)
        {
            populateData();
        }
    }

    private void populateData()
    {

        // here code for populate data
        using (TrialEntities17 dc = new TrialEntities17())
        {
            var v = (from p in dc.Vehicle_Andon
                     where (p.Line_Name == DropDownList1.SelectedValue
                      && p.Loss_Type == 9 && p.Date_Time == Date1.Value)
                     join s in dc.LOSS_TYPE_MASTER on p.Loss_Description equals s.Loss_Description
                     select new
                     {
                         p,
                         s.Loss_Description,
                     });
            List<Vehicle_Andon> allP = new List<Vehicle_Andon>();

            foreach (var i in v)
            {
                Vehicle_Andon p = new Vehicle_Andon();
                p = i.p;
                p.Loss_Description = i.Loss_Description;
                
                allP.Add(p);
            }

            GridView1.DataSource = allP;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }

    private List<LOSS_TYPE_MASTER> populateState()
    {
        // here code for populate state
        List<LOSS_TYPE_MASTER> all = new List<LOSS_TYPE_MASTER>();
        using (TrialEntities17 dc = new TrialEntities17())
        {
            all = dc.LOSS_TYPE_MASTER.ToList();
        }
        return all;

    }

      
    private List<string> populateCity(int Loss_Type)

    {
        using (TrialEntities17 dc = new TrialEntities17())
            // here code for populate city based on stateID
            if (Loss_Type == 1)
        {
            List<LINE_CONFIGRATOR> all = new List<LINE_CONFIGRATOR>();

                all = dc.LINE_CONFIGRATOR
                            .Where(a => (a.Line_Name == DropDownList1.SelectedValue && a.Loss_Type.Equals(Loss_Type) && a.STATION == L2.Text)).ToList();
            }

            else if (Loss_Type == 2)
        {
            List<LINE_SKILL_CONFIG> all = new List<LINE_SKILL_CONFIG>();

                all = dc.LINE_SKILL_CONFIG
                            .Where(b => (b.Line_Name == DropDownList1.SelectedValue && b.Loss_Type.Equals(Loss_Type) && b.STATION == L2.Text)).ToList();
        }
        return all;
    }


    protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
        
        string loss_type = GridView1.DataKeys[e.NewEditIndex]["Loss_Type"].ToString();
        string station = GridView1.DataKeys[e.NewEditIndex]["Station"].ToString();
        
        // Edit Event
        GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
        populateData();

        // Here populate data for dropdown state
        DropDownList ddLoss_DescriptionEdit = (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].FindControl("ddLoss_Description");
        if (ddLoss_DescriptionEdit != null)
        {
            ddLoss_DescriptionEdit.DataSource = populateState();
            ddLoss_DescriptionEdit.DataTextField = "Loss_Description";
            ddLoss_DescriptionEdit.DataValueField = "Loss_Type";
            ddLoss_DescriptionEdit.DataBind();
            ddLoss_DescriptionEdit.SelectedValue = loss_type;
        }

        string V = (GridView1.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].FindControl("txtStation1") as Label).Text.Trim();
        L2.Text = V;

        DropDownList ddReasonEdit = (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].FindControl("ddReason");
        if (ddReasonEdit != null)
        {
            ddReasonEdit.DataSource = populateCity(Convert.ToInt32(loss_type));
            ddReasonEdit.DataTextField = "Reason";
            ddReasonEdit.DataValueField = "Station";
            ddReasonEdit.DataBind();
            ddReasonEdit.SelectedValue = station;
        }
    }

    protected void GridView1_RowCancelingEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
        populateData();
    }

    protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        // Here Update
        int Master_ID = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values["Master_ID"].ToString());
        DropDownList ddLoss_DescriptionEdit = (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("ddLoss_Description");
        DropDownList ddReasonEdit = (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("ddReason");
        TextBox txtStationEdit = (TextBox)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtStation");

        using (TrialEntities17 dc = new TrialEntities17())
        {
            Vehicle_Andon p = dc.Vehicle_Andon.Where(a => a.Master_ID.Equals(Master_ID)).FirstOrDefault();
            if (p != null)
            {
                p.Loss_Type = Convert.ToInt32(ddLoss_DescriptionEdit.SelectedValue);
                p.Loss_Description = ddLoss_DescriptionEdit.SelectedItem.ToString();
                p.Reason = ddReasonEdit.SelectedItem.ToString();
                dc.SaveChanges();
                GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
                populateData();
            }
        }

    }

    protected void ddLoss_Description_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Populate city
        string Loss_Type = ((DropDownList)sender).SelectedValue;
        int rowIndex = GridView1.EditIndex;
        DropDownList ddReasonEdit = (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].FindControl("ddReason");
        if (ddReasonEdit != null)
        {
            var v = populateCity(Convert.ToInt32(Loss_Type));
            ddReasonEdit.DataSource = v;
            ddReasonEdit.DataBind();
            if (ddReasonEdit.Items.Count > 0)
            {
                ddReasonEdit.SelectedIndex = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

I'm new with Linq query

[Edited list as String](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ter2j.png)

[After new edit for Object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9lqO.png)

[After edit Error for .dc and .obj](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q47s9.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//first List
List<LINE_CONFIGRATOR> all = new List<LINE_CONFIGRATOR>(); 
//Second 
List<LINE_SKILL_CONFIG> all = new List<LINE_SKILL_CONFIG>();
```

Your both list are different and function returns list of string first you need to select string list from linq query. please try following code.

```
//Solutions 
  
public class ClassName
{ 
       public string Station { get; set; }
       public string Reason { get; set; }
}
private List<ClassName> populateCity(int Loss_Type)

{
     using (TrialEntities17 dc = new TrialEntities17())
     List<ClassName> obj = new List<ClassName>();
    if (Loss_Type == 1)
    {
        obj = (from p in dc.LINE_CONFIGRATOR
        where p.Line_Name == DropDownList1.SelectedValue && 
        p.Loss_Type.Equals(Loss_Type) && p.STATION == L2.Text
        select new ClassName
         {
           Station = p.Station,
           Reason = p.Reason
         }).ToList();
}
else if (Loss_Type == 2)
{
      obj = (from p in dc.LINE_SKILL_CONFIG
             where p.Line_Name == DropDownList1.SelectedValue && 
             p.Loss_Type.Equals(Loss_Type) && p.STATION == L2.Text
              select new ClassName
             {
             Station = p.Station,
             Reason = p.Reason
             }).ToList();
    
}
return obj;

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Pawan for the help, but the issue is that *string* defined by me actually doesn't contain any data.

Comment: I even want to know, what could I use in the function LIST<here> populate(int Loss_Type) since the condition are taking data from different tables.

Comment: show me the model  class LINE_CONFIGRATOR  and LINE_SKILL_CONFIG.

Comment: namespace Loss_Portal
    {
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    
    public partial class LINE_SKILL_CONFIG
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int Loss_Type { get; set; }
        public string STATION { get; set; }
        public string OPERATOR_NO { get; set; }
        public string Reason { get; set; }
        public string SKILL { get; set; }
        public string Line_Name { get; set; }
    }
    }

Comment: namespace Loss_Portal
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    
    public partial class LINE_CONFIGRATOR
    {
        public int LineID { get; set; }
        public int Loss_Type { get; set; }
        public string STATION { get; set; }
        public string MACHINE_ID { get; set; }
        public string Reason { get; set; }
        public string Line_Name { get; set; }
    }
}

Comment: In both class  which parameter  do you want in list ? STATION

Comment: So you need to select STATION in your linq query.

Comment: i need Reason in the list

Comment: you can select REASON in list because its also string type.

Comment: Yes, i've selected Reason as per your guidance and attached image at end of my question. But when i run the code it shows the following error: 'DataBinding: 'System.String' does not contain a property with the name 'Reason'.'

Comment: Answer modified please check

Comment: Yes, i tried the edited one.. I've posted the images at the last, there are error fo .dc and .obj in the code that's what it's showing

Comment: please check again modified

Comment: update function return type also private List<ClassName> populateCity(int Loss_Type)

Comment: Thank you so much Pawan for the help. Now both the dropdownlist are working good and properly. Again thank you very much for your time, guidance and solution to my question

Comment: if answer is helpful for you please accept or mark.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70847551/how-to-update-selecteditem-in-cascading-dropdownlist-in-the-sql-database if possible, can you please help for this problem sir @PawanLakhara