# How to update SelectedItem of Cascading dropdownlist in the SQL Database

Tags: c#, asp.net, aspxgridview, cascadingdropdown

I have 2 dropdownlist using Cascading method. But everytime the 1st item of 2nd dropdownlist gets updated in the database even if choose 2nd or 3rd item from the dropdownlist.

[Selection from 2nd Dropdownlist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0utEY.png)

If I view my Database, it shows the *Frame Hoist* updated in Reason column instead of *Number Punching m/c*

[Database image of updated data after selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQ3jU.png)

Please find below my .cs code

```
namespace Loss_Portal
{
public partial class _Default : Page
{

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsPostBack)
        {
            populateData();
        }
    }

    private void populateData()
    {

        // here code for populate person data
        using (TrialEntities20 dc = new TrialEntities20())
        {
            var v = (from p in dc.Vehicle_Andon
                     where (p.Line_Name == DropDownList1.SelectedValue
                      && p.Loss_Type == 9 && p.Date_Time == Date1.Value)
                     join s in dc.LOSS_TYPE_MASTER on p.Loss_Description equals s.Loss_Description
                     select new
                     {
                         p,
                         s.Loss_Description,
                     });
            List<Vehicle_Andon> allP = new List<Vehicle_Andon>();

            foreach (var i in v)
            {
                Vehicle_Andon p = new Vehicle_Andon();
                p = i.p;
                p.Loss_Description = i.Loss_Description;

                allP.Add(p);
            }

            GridView1.DataSource = allP;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }

    private List<LOSS_TYPE_MASTER> populateState()
    {
        // here code for populate state
        List<LOSS_TYPE_MASTER> all = new List<LOSS_TYPE_MASTER>();
        using (TrialEntities20 dc = new TrialEntities20())
        {
            all = dc.LOSS_TYPE_MASTER.ToList();
        }
        return all;

    }

    public class ClassName
    {
        public string Station { get; set; }
        public string Reason { get; set; }
    }

    private List<ClassName> populateCity(int Loss_Type)
    {
        List<ClassName> obj = new List<ClassName>();
        using (TrialEntities20 dc = new TrialEntities20())

            if (Loss_Type == 1)
            {

                obj = (from p in dc.LINE_CONFIGRATOR
                       where p.Line_Name == DropDownList1.SelectedValue && p.STATION == L2.Text
                       select new ClassName
                       {
                           Station = p.STATION,
                           Reason = p.Reason
                       }).ToList();
            }
            else if (Loss_Type == 6)
            {
                obj = (from p in dc.LINE_SKILL_CONFIG
                       where p.Line_Name == DropDownList1.SelectedValue && p.STATION == L2.Text
                       select new ClassName
                       {
                           Station = p.STATION,
                           Reason = p.Reason
                       }).ToList();
            }
            else if (Loss_Type == 8)
            {
                obj = (from p in dc.MATERIAL_SHORTAGE
                       where p.Line_Name == DropDownList1.SelectedValue && p.STATION == L2.Text
                       select new ClassName
                       {
                           Station = p.STATION,
                           Reason = p.Reason
                       }).ToList();
            }
        return obj;
    }

    


    protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {

        string loss_type = GridView1.DataKeys[e.NewEditIndex]["Loss_Type"].ToString();
        string station = GridView1.DataKeys[e.NewEditIndex]["Station"].ToString();

        // Edit Event
        GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
        populateData();

        // Here populate data for dropdown state
        DropDownList ddLoss_DescriptionEdit = (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].FindControl("ddLoss_Description");
        if (ddLoss_DescriptionEdit != null)
        {
            ddLoss_DescriptionEdit.DataSource = populateState();
            ddLoss_DescriptionEdit.DataTextField = "Loss_Description";
            ddLoss_DescriptionEdit.DataValueField = "Loss_Type";
            ddLoss_DescriptionEdit.DataBind();
            ddLoss_DescriptionEdit.SelectedValue = loss_type;
        }

        

        string V = (GridView1.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].FindControl("txtStation") as Label).Text.Trim();
        L2.Text = V;

        DropDownList ddReasonEdit = (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].FindControl("ddReason");
        if (ddReasonEdit != null)
        {
            ddReasonEdit.DataSource = populateCity(Convert.ToInt32(loss_type));
            ddReasonEdit.DataTextField = "Reason";
            ddReasonEdit.DataValueField = "Station";
            ddReasonEdit.DataBind();
            ddReasonEdit.SelectedValue = station;
        }

        
    }

    protected void GridView1_RowCancelingEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
        populateData();
    }

    protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        // Here Update
        int Master_ID = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values["Master_ID"].ToString());
        DropDownList ddLoss_DescriptionEdit = (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("ddLoss_Description");
        DropDownList ddReasonEdit = (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("ddReason");
        Label txtStationEdit = (Label)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtStation");

        using (TrialEntities20 dc = new TrialEntities20())
        {
            Vehicle_Andon p = dc.Vehicle_Andon.Where(a => a.Master_ID.Equals(Master_ID)).FirstOrDefault();
            if (p != null)
            {
                p.Loss_Type = Convert.ToInt32(ddLoss_DescriptionEdit.SelectedValue);
                p.Loss_Description = ddLoss_DescriptionEdit.SelectedItem.ToString();
                p.Reason = ddReasonEdit.SelectedItem.ToString();
                dc.SaveChanges();
                GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
                populateData();
            }
           

        }

    }

    protected void ddLoss_Description_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Populate city
        {
            string Loss_Type = ((DropDownList)sender).SelectedValue;
            int rowIndex = GridView1.EditIndex;
            DropDownList ddReasonEdit = (DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].FindControl("ddReason");
            if (ddReasonEdit != null)
            {
                var v = populateCity(Convert.ToInt32(Loss_Type));
                ddReasonEdit.DataSource = v;
                ddReasonEdit.DataBind();
                if (ddReasonEdit.Items.Count > 0)
                {
                    ddReasonEdit.SelectedIndex = 0;
                }
            }
        }

        
    }
}
}
```

html code

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

  <h3>Loss Portal</h3>
    <div style="margin-left: 300px">
        
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Select Date :" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Arial Black" Font-Overline="False"></asp:Label>
        &nbsp;
        <input id="Date1" runat="server" type="date" /><asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="requiredfieldvalidator" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Date1" ErrorMessage="Date is Required" ForeColor="Red" style="z-index: 1; top: 109px; position: absolute; left: 720px" />
        <br />
        <br />
        
        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Arial Black" Text="Select Line :"></asp:Label>

        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="Line_Name" DataValueField="Line_Name" Height="28px" Width="211px">
        </asp:DropDownList><asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="requiredfieldvalidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="DropDownList1" ErrorMessage="Select Line" ForeColor="Red" style="z-index: 1; top: 154px; position: absolute; left: 720px" />
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:TrialConnectionString2 %>" SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT [Line_Name] FROM [Vehicle_Andon] ORDER BY [Line_Name]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
        <br />

        <br />

        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" CssClass="btn-primary-active" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Submit" Width="180px" Height="31px" />
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="L2" runat="server"  Visible="false"/>
        <br />
        </div>
        <div style="margin-left: 0px">
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
       CellPadding="4" onrowediting="GridView1_RowEditing"  DataKeyNames="Loss_Type,Station,Master_ID"
       onrowcancelingedit="GridView1_RowCancelingEdit"
       onrowupdating="GridView1_RowUpdating" GridLines="None" ForeColor="#333333" >
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
    <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Master_ID &nbsp;" HeaderStyle-Width="30px" HeaderStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle" Visible="false">
                     <ItemTemplate>
                         <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("Master_ID")%>' runat="server"  Width="70px"/>
                     </ItemTemplate>
                     <EditItemTemplate>
                         <asp:Label ID="txtMaster_ID" Text='<%# Eval("Master_ID")%>' runat="server" />
                     </EditItemTemplate>                        
                     <HeaderStyle VerticalAlign="Middle" Width="30px"></HeaderStyle>
                    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="30px"></HeaderStyle>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Station No." HeaderStyle-Wrap="false" HeaderStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                      <ItemTemplate>
                     <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("Station")%>' runat="server" Width="82px" />
                     </ItemTemplate>
                      <EditItemTemplate>
                       <asp:Label ID="txtStation" Text='<%# Eval("Station")%>' runat="server" />
                        </EditItemTemplate>                        
                      <HeaderStyle VerticalAlign="Middle" Wrap="False" HorizontalAlign="Justify"></HeaderStyle>
                    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="30px"></HeaderStyle>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Conveyor No." HeaderStyle-Wrap="false" HeaderStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                      <ItemTemplate>
                     <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("Conveyor")%>' runat="server" Width="80px"/>
                     </ItemTemplate>
                      <EditItemTemplate>
                       <asp:Label ID="txtConveyor" Text='<%# Eval("Conveyor")%>' runat="server" />
                        </EditItemTemplate>                        
                      <HeaderStyle VerticalAlign="Middle" Wrap="False" HorizontalAlign="Center"></HeaderStyle>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Andon_PC " HeaderStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                      <ItemTemplate>
                          <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("Andon_PC")%>' runat="server" Width="75px" />
                     </ItemTemplate>
                      <EditItemTemplate>
                          <asp:Label ID="txtAndon_PC" Text='<%# Eval("Andon_PC")%>' runat="server" />
                        </EditItemTemplate>                        
                      <HeaderStyle VerticalAlign="Middle" Wrap="False" HorizontalAlign="Center"></HeaderStyle>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Start_Time " HeaderStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                      <ItemTemplate>
                     <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("Start_Time")%>' runat="server"  Width="200px"/>
                     </ItemTemplate>
                      <EditItemTemplate>
                       <asp:Label ID="txtStart_Time" Text='<%# Eval("Start_Time")%>' runat="server" />
                        </EditItemTemplate>                        
                      <HeaderStyle VerticalAlign="Middle" Wrap="False" HorizontalAlign="Center"></HeaderStyle>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Close_Time " HeaderStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                      <ItemTemplate>
                     <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("Close_Time")%>' runat="server"  Width="200px"/>
                     </ItemTemplate>
                      <EditItemTemplate>
                       <asp:Label ID="txtClose_Time" Text='<%# Eval("Close_Time")%>' runat="server" />
                        </EditItemTemplate>                        
                      <HeaderStyle VerticalAlign="Middle" Wrap="False" HorizontalAlign="Center"></HeaderStyle>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Duration" HeaderStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                      <ItemTemplate>
                     <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("Duration")%>' runat="server" />
                     </ItemTemplate>
                      <EditItemTemplate>
                       <asp:Label ID="txtDuration" Text='<%# Eval("Duration")%>' runat="server" Width="55px"/>
                        </EditItemTemplate>                        
                      <HeaderStyle VerticalAlign="Middle" Wrap="False" HorizontalAlign="Center"></HeaderStyle>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Line_Name" HeaderStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                      <ItemTemplate>
                          <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("Line_Name")%>' runat="server" Width="155px" />
                     </ItemTemplate>
                      <EditItemTemplate>
                          <asp:Label ID="txtLine_Name" Text='<%# Eval("Line_Name")%>' runat="server" />
                        </EditItemTemplate>                        
                      <HeaderStyle VerticalAlign="Middle" Wrap="False" HorizontalAlign="Center"></HeaderStyle>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Loss_Description" HeaderStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                      <ItemTemplate>
                     <asp:Label ID="ltype" Text='<%# Eval("Loss_Description")%>' runat="server" Width="150px"/>
                     </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                       <asp:DropdownList ID="ddLoss_Description" DataTextField="Loss_Descripiton" DataValueField="Loss_Type"
                                runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexchanged="ddLoss_Description_SelectedIndexChanged" >
                            </asp:DropdownList>
                        </EditItemTemplate>                        
                        <HeaderStyle VerticalAlign="Middle" Wrap="False" HorizontalAlign="Center"></HeaderStyle>
                </asp:TemplateField>

              
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Reason" HeaderStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                      <ItemTemplate>
                     <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("Reason")%>' runat="server" Width="100px" />
                     </ItemTemplate>
                      <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:DropdownList ID="ddReason" runat="server" DataTextField="Reason" DataValueField="Station">
                            </asp:DropdownList>
                      </EditItemTemplate>
                    <HeaderStyle VerticalAlign="Middle" Wrap="False" HorizontalAlign="Center"></HeaderStyle>
                </asp:TemplateField>


              <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-Width="120px">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:ImageButton ImageUrl="imgs/edit.png" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("Master_ID") %>' ToolTip="Edit" Width="25px" Height="25px" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:ImageButton ImageUrl="imgs/save.png" runat="server" CommandName="Update" ToolTip="Update" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("Master_ID") %>' Width="25px" Height="25px" />
                        <asp:ImageButton ImageUrl="imgs/cancel.png" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" ToolTip="Cancel" Width="25px" Height="25px" />
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                        <HeaderStyle VerticalAlign="Middle" Wrap="False" HorizontalAlign="Center"></HeaderStyle>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
            <EditRowStyle BorderColor="#99CCFF" BorderStyle="Dotted" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" BackColor="#3399FF" />
       <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" ForeColor="White" Font-Bold="True" />
       <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" BorderColor="#003366" BorderStyle="Solid" Width="50px" Wrap="False" />
       <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" BorderStyle="Solid" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" BorderColor="#003366" />
       <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" BorderStyle="Dotted" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
       <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />
       <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
       <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />
       <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
   </asp:GridView>
    </div>

</asp:Content>
```

I'm new to Linq query and I need to complete my project.

Please, could someone help ?

Comment: @pawanlakhara I would request you to help, since you already know the content of the code to large extent

Comment: You are not saving station value check your update or save code.

Comment: No sir, I need to Save Reason which I select from 2nd dropdopwnlist but it default takes the 1st value of the list in the database

Comment: @PawanLakhara sir i've also updated my html code in the question for your reference.

Comment: @PawanLakhara sir could you please suggest any changes in order to get the selected value in the database as well